# CRM dynamics web api (400) Bad Request

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, webclient, asp.net-web-api2

I have a crm dynamics plugin that makes a web api call but I am getting the following error:

```
The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request
```

I am using the following code

```
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                string URI = "http://myserver/api/myaction";
                string myParameters = string.Format("param1={0}", param1);

                using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
                {
                    wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                    string HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(URI, myParameters);
                }
            }
```

When I profile and debug this with the Plugin Registration tool the web api call returns a valid result and does not error.

Any ideas what is causing this infuriating issue?

UPDATE:
The plugin is running in sandbox mode and is on premise.
We have tried using async HttpClient but this requires the referencing of additional dlls which causes it own issues (adding the dlls to the  GAC/ ILMerge) hence trying to get a working solution with WebClient initially which requires no additional dll referencing.

Comment: Is your plugin running in isolation/sandbox mode (option for on-prem/required for online) and is it async? Is your WebAPI using authentication?

Comment: Also, have you tried tracing (http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/tracing-in-aspnet-web-api) on the WebApi side?

Comment: I have added some addional info @Nicknow

Comment: Any luck with tracing? The trace on the WebApi side should tell you why it is returning a 400 error.

Answer (score -1):

The issue turned out to be caused by an IIS binding issue.

Comment: Please add some more detail, especially when you are answering your own question...how was the site bound and what change did you need to change the site's binding to be to resolve the issue? This will help future readers who may have the same problem.